# How to fold and expand wpf Tabitem

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a requirement to create Wpf tabcontrol with several tabItems.
 Now this tabitems are aligned in horizontal and it occupy as two rows.
 I want it in one row with fold and expand facility.Can anyone help?

Comment: Any sample image use have

Comment: Try to update your question with more details so that we can understand your problem.